# Android - Webview Cuts Off on Smaller Screen

Tags: android, xml, webview

I have a Google Calendar that I'm trying to display in my Android app, but when I do, it gets cut off on my HTC Incredible 2. It displays fine on my Nexus 7. I've tried working with the answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012936/android-webview-cuts-off) but still no luck. Any help would be *awesome*. Thank you!

```
  public class Events extends SherlockActivity
  {
    boolean isLoaded = false;
ActionBar actionBar;
WebView eventView;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.events);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    eventView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.eventsView);
    eventView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    final Activity activity = this;

    /* Cut out loading screen, etc */

    eventView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&mode=MONTH&height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23ffffff&src=fresnochaffeezoo%40gmail.com&color=%23182C57&ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles");

}



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/eventsView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following settings help with the way the page is rendered initially:

```
eventView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort( false );
eventView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode( true );
```

optionally:

```
eventView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom( ZoomLevel. ... );
```